# while loop not stopping

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to populate a text field but my while loop its not working its stuck i the loop. Can you please let me know what I doing wrong?

```
mainStatus = ['vehicleList[0].mainStatus','vehicleList[1].mainStatus','vehicleList[2].mainStatus','vehicleList[3].mainStatus','vehicleList[4].mainStatus','vehicleList[5].mainStatus','vehicleList[6].mainStatus','vehicleList[7].mainStatus']
subStatus = ['vehicleList[0].subStatus','vehicleList[1].subStatus','vehicleList[2].subStatus','vehicleList[3].subStatus','vehicleList[4].subStatus','vehicleList[5].subStatus','vehicleList[6].subStatus','vehicleList[7].subStatus']
i = 0

while browser.text_field(:name => 'selection').value == ''
    if browser.span(:name => mainStatus[i]).text == 'AVAILABLE' && (browser.span(:name => subStatus[i]).exists?) == false
        browser.text_field(:name => 'selection').set (i + 1).to_s
        browser.button(:name => "OpSelect").click
    else 
        i + 1   
    end
        if i == 8 && browser.button(:name => "OpSelect").click.exists?
            browser.button(:name => "OpSelect").click
            i = 0
        end
end
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to do. Nothing satisfies the end of loop condition. If the selection text_field is blank, then type something into the selection text_field and click the opselect button. Does the text_field go blank again? Assuming you get to i==8, then you click the opselect button. But what makes the selection text_field ever become populated when re-approaching the while statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while browser.text_field(:name => 'selection').value == ''
    if browser.span(:name => mainStatus[i]).text == 'AVAILABLE' && (browser.span(:name => subStatus[i]).exists?) == false
        browser.text_field(:name => 'selection').set (i + 1).to_s
        browser.button(:name => "OpSelect").click
    end
        i = i + 1   
            if i == 8 && browser.button(:name => "OpSelect").click.exists?
                browser.button(:name => "OpSelect").click
                i = 0
            end

end
```

Comment: If this is a revised version of above, please edit your question and not post an answer to it.